# What's the best way to put a database-driven app on Codeplex?

Tags: database, codeplex

I'm primarily an ASP.NET developer and I'm hoping to move a few projects to Codeplex and open them up to the community. Most of my applications are database-driven, so I'm faced with the question of how I should deal with the database. Should I post the schema and expect contributors to build/host their own database? Should I include a database file in the project? Should I find a way to host a community database?

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think posting scripts to create the database, and populate any needed data would be sufficient.  I don't think it's too much to expect for people to get SQL Server Express, or some other free database, and host their own copy of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why not offer all three? If you can find a place to host the database, making the schema scripts and including the DB file is simple. The projects I have used simple have a create script.